# formula causing segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I dont understand why I am getting a segmentation error 11 in the console when I enter my number 1 to 4. When I bypass the velocity formula it works but I can't find out how to fix the formula.
I have created this code for a school assignment which wants me to print the 4 struct arrays and prompt the user to pick one and then using the one the user picked to calculate the velocity of that channel and output it.

```
/*----------------------------------------
file: A4Q2.c
author: Wahhaaj Salam
description: Program presents the characteristics of four rectangular channels and prompts the user to select one of the channels and after calculate the chnnels velocity and displays results
 -----------------------------------------------*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
// function prototypes

typedef struct
{
// variable declarations
char name[100]; // Channel name
float n; // roughness
float slope; // slope
float width; // width
float depth; // depth
} CHANNEL;

void printchannels(CHANNEL channels[4]);
float velocity(CHANNEL channels[4], int x);

void main (){
CHANNEL channels[4] =
{
    {"Channel 1", 0.035, 0.0001, 10.0, 2,0},
    {"Channel 2", 0.020, 0.0002, 8.0, 1.0},
    {"Channel 3", 0.015, 0.0010, 20.0, 1.5},
    {"Channel 4", 0.030, 0.007, 24.0, 3.0},

};
printchannels(channels);
int x;
float v;
printf("Make a selection(1 to 4):");
scanf("%f", &x);
v = velocity(channels,x);
printf("the velocity is: %f", v);
}

void printchannels(CHANNEL channels[4])
{
int i;
for ( i = 0; i <4; i++){
    printf("%s ", channels[i].name);
    printf("%.3f  ", channels[i].n);
    printf("%.4f  ", channels[i].slope);
    printf("%.1f ", channels[i].width);
    printf("%.1f \n", channels[i].depth);

}

}

float velocity(CHANNEL channels[4], int x)
{
float v;
v=(channels[x-1].width/channels[x-1].depth);
v=v/(channels[x-1].width + (2*channels[x-1].depth));
v=pow(v,0.6666666666667);
v=v*(sqrt(channels[x-1].slope)/channels[x-1].n);
return v;
}
```

Comment: Note that you should be checking the return value from `scanf()`, just to check that it was happy.  One of the most basic debugging techniques is to print the value that you've read to make sure your program is seeing what you expect it to see.  Printing `x` would have told you something was wrong.  And a good compiler would have warned you about the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare

```
int x;
```

Then you wrongly scan `x` as a float: value is not likely to be within 1 and 4

```
scanf("%f", &x);
```

then you pass the value to your routine: array out of bounds!

correct code (which protects you from user wrong inputs as a bonus) would be:

```
while(1)
{
  printf("Make a selection(1 to 4):");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  if ((x>0) && (x<5)) break;  // boundary checking
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing a `float` in an `int` variable:

```
int x;
float v;
printf("Make a selection(1 to 4):");
scanf("%f", &x);
```